# Using Query & WHERE or FILTER to reference a sheet and filter by column fed by Pull-down menu

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am trying to just list rows from a sheet into a new sheet, filtered by by text in Col F, which comes from a drop-down menu. In the file: I want to see all rows of I-Alpha and E Alpha, for example, in one new sheet, without filtering the origin sheet.

I tried to conduct a simple Query (from Sheet Account1 for example) to another sheet (SimpleQuery&WHere) in same file and then filter according to text in column F of origin sheet. This text is entered by means of a pull-down menu, listed in another sheet (Categories).

From what I have read,

=Query( Account1!A1:G17 , "select A, B, C, D, E WHERE F = 'I-alpha' ")

should do it, but I get Parse Error.

Is this because the text comes from a pull-down menu?

Have a made a mistake somewhere? Would something else work better?

File:
[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U79oTuuDiRm_Hv6XwDv-YR0UdXb-QDs2vjsEokeUULc/edit?usp=sharing](https://stackoverflow.com)

I have tried:
=Query( Account1!A1:G17 , "select A, B, C, D, E where F = 'I-alpha' ")

=FILTER( Account1!A1:J7 , REGEXMATCH(f1:f7, "I-Delta"))

=Query( Account1!A1:G17 , "select A, B, C, D, E where F contains 'alpha' ")

ALL Parse error.

Please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sheet locale uses `semicolon` convention instead of `comma`; you may try:

```
=query(Account1!A1:G17;"select A, B, C, D, E where F = 'I-alpha'")
```

[image]

Comment: That worked! I had no idea. Thanks so much! I cannot upvote yet, but anyone else who comes by this, please do! As an aside: I do indeed live in Brazil at the moment, and some of my preferences are set to Brazil, some to UK, some to US -  so that may be why.